# Is it possible to configure multiple queues to one shovel?

Tags: rabbitmq

I've got a webservice that accepts messages that can be sent to a RabbitMQ cluster using whatever queue they define. This is so front-end devs can send messages via javascript.

I want to make the webservice more robust so that when we have network trouble, the webservice can still accept messages and then handle them when the network is back up. After some initial reading, it seems that the Shovel plugin should handle this nicely.

What I was thinking was to install a local instance of RabbitMQ on the webservice box with shovel turned on. I can then send all messages through the local RabbitMQ instance and have it push all messages to the cluster and deal with the network problems.

My problem is after looking at the documentation it seems that I have to configure every queue I want to forward to in the shovel config file. If that's the case I'm not sure this will work since we allow clients to define a queue through the webservice on the fly.

I would like to have the webservice take the messages, hand them off to the local rmq instance and have it pass the messages off to the cluster using the same queues/exachanges/etc.

Has anyone tried this or can explain how the shovel plugin works?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered sending messages to an exchange instead of a queue.  Send all messages to one exchange possibly a topic exchange if you need that kind of flexibility.  Then have the consumer handle the different messages or different queues from the exchange.  Sending to one exchange would make configuring the shovel considerably easier.

Comment: That sounds like something to try... if I were to have the one exchange with multiple queues, would I be able to name the queues programmatically or can that only happen in the shovel config?

Comment: The queues could be created and named by the consumer, so yes programatically.  I am not an expert at shovel.